# Saving band math output as TIFF using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, raster, raster-calculator

I'm trying to do some band math using ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro. I want the output to be a TIFF file. However, my following code is outputting in GRID format even though the input is TIFF.

```
band1 = "C:\Geoprocessing\_band_1_rast1"

Raster_Calculator = band1

raster1 = arcpy.Raster(r"C:\image.tif")

band1 = raster1 * 100000

band1.save(Raster_Calculator)
```

How can I add code to make the output TIFF?

Comment: @Vince Sorry, fixed the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `.tif` extension when you save the raster, otherwise it will save to grid format. It is a good practice to explicitly define your input and output rasters. Here are the changes I would make:

```
in_raster =  r"C:\image.tif"
out_raster = r"C:\Geoprocessing\band_1_rast1.tif"

raster1 = arcpy.Raster(in_raster)

band1 = raster1 * 100000

band1.save(out_raster)
```